# Using Variable as Keyword Argument for Function

Tags: python, function, variables, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I have the following piece of code:

```
quantity_of_units = int(funding_time_left.split[0])
unit_of_measurement = funding_time_left.split()[1]
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if unit_of_measurement == 'days':
    end = (now + timedelta(days=quantity_of_units)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
elif unit_of_measurement == 'hours':
    end = (now + timedelta(hours=quantity_of_units)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
else: # unit_of_measure == 'minutes'
    end = (now + timedelta(minutes=quantity_of_units)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
funding.append([aeles.get_attribute('href'), end])
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use a variable (`unit_of_measurement`) as the keyword argument (`days`, `hours`, `minutes`)?

If it is indeed possible, I could scrap the `if elif else` block altogether and turn it all into a single line. Below is what I'm hoping to do.

```
quantity_of_units = int(funding_time_left.split[0])
unit_of_measurement = funding_time_left.split()[1]
now = datetime.datetime.now()
end = (now + timedelta(unit_of_measurement=quantity_of_units)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
funding.append([aeles.get_attribute('href'), end])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, by using `**` to unpack a `dict` in the arguments, which sets them to be keyword arguments.

```
timedelta(**{unit_of_measurement: quantity_of_units})
```

The reason why it works is because that unpacks to:

```
timedelta(<unit_of_measurement>=quantity_of_units)
```

Where `<unit_of_measurement>` is `minutes`, `seconds`, `days`...

---

So you can replace your `if... elif... else...` statements with:

```
end = (now + timedelta(**{unit_of_measurement: quantity_of_units})).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: can you elaborate. im new to python. im not sure what the `**` does nor why i would have to include both the `key` and `value` of the dictionary?

Comment: @Anthony you can see this post if you're unsure what `**` does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926/6622817

Comment: i've just edited my question. can you please look? thanks for the link, i'll check it out right now!

Comment: Even after your edits, I'm still fairly confident that my solution can replace your `if... elif... else...` statements. Just give it a try :)

Comment: i'm goign to test this right now and ill mark as correct if it works

Comment: so when i unpack the dict via `**{u:q}` it basically converts it to `u=q`??? instead of writing `timedelta(**{unit_of_measurement: quantity_of_units} = quantity_of_units)`, i can just write `timedelta(**{unit_of_measurement: quantity_of_units})`??

Comment: @Anthony correct, where `u` is the evaluated keyword argument string.

Comment: wow, that's amazing!! i'm amazed at all the cool stuff python is capable of doing!!